# how can i remove token from specific Api route in laravel

Tags: api, jwt, token, middleware, laravel-6

I use JWT token in my project and i have an Api route that i want to remove token that send from user.
I searched a lot and many people say to put my route in $except array in VerifyCsrfToken class , but it does not work.
I want this solution because if user send request with token, the result that returned is differ from result that returned without token.

///edited

I have one route without middleware and guard, in Product model i wrote a global scope that affect on is_active column.

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        if (Auth::guard('manager')->check()) {

            return $builder;
        }


        if (Auth::guard('customer')->check()) {

            return $builder->where('is_active', '=',true);
        }

        return $builder->where('is_active', '=',true);
    }
```

if manager use this route for products, all products returned.
i want the user's role have no effect on output.
in other word i want to remove token from some api routes

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand your question.

But isn't it possible to just adequately add one layer of middleware and do your filtering there?
So you could check if the user has a token or not and react accordingly (like forwarding the user on a specific route).
In case that may help, you can find a few [middleware related videos here](https://tutorama.info/CTG/MiddleWare) explaining how it works.

Comment: I edited my post with extra details.
i have many controller and i want to delete token in a middleware for same result for managers and customers

Answer (score 1):

VerifyCsrToken is for CSRF and it's different with JWT token.

In this situation you have 2 different solution:

1. When your user is sending JWT token, It means your user was authenticated, and you can get user's object and send proper response.
2. You could make 2 different controller, and two routes, one of them for without token and another one with token, And according to user request, make your proper response.

Comment: I edited my post with extra details.
i have many controller and i want to delete token in a middleware for same result for managers and customers